# Select Random UIACollectionCell using Appium

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying perform automation on iOS device. In once scenario, I have UIACollectionCell which is a list view. Is there anyway using Appium+Java, I can select random Cell every time I run the test.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
List<MobileElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell"));
Random rnd = new Random();
int rndInt = rnd.nextInt(elements.size());
elements.get(rndInt).click();
```

List of elements with findElement**s**() is created with the query that matches the first UIACollectionView (specified with the index [1]) and all the UIACollectionCell elements inside it. This should give you a List of all UIACollectionCell elements inside the specified UIACollectionView.

For even more precise query you could also use:

```
List<MobileElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell"));
```

Comment: Thank You, will try this

Comment: I am getting following error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Comment: The List didn't have any UIACell elements in that case. Did you check if my xpath queries match with your app?
I guessed those queries, but if you want, you can also share the app structure by printing the contents of `driver.getPageSource();` and editing it into your question. Then I can edit the queries to match.

Comment: Are you able to copy a full Xpath of the UIACollectionCell as well as one of the UIACell elements you want to interact with? You can find the full Xpath by inspecting the app via Appium Inspector.

Comment: This is the actual xpath of the first Collection Cell. { //UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]  }

Comment: Do u require any more info @Domestus

Comment: The xpath of one of the UIACells would also help. I assume they are all located under UIACollectionCell[1] ?
Is this the only UIACollectionCell in the view? If not, we might need to make the query more specified to get the correct UIACollectionCell. For example:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]"));`

Comment: There are more than 10. They are in list view one after another

Comment: I have edited my answer to directly find all UIACell components from under any UIACollectionCell. You can edit the findElements command to something like this also:
`driver.findElements(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView‌​[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]/UIACell"));`

Comment: I've updated the answer now after re-reading your example of the first actual UIACollectionCell. The assumption is now that there are multiple UIACollectionCell elements under UIACollectionView and we want to get a List of all those UIACollectionCells.

Comment: it still shows an error..... An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: elementId 15 could not be tapped

Comment: Are you able to tap on such element directly?
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIACollectionView‌​[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]").click();`

Comment: No I cannot. It works when I use following                          `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()[0].tap();");`